# How do I change the name of a poco on the client with RIA Services?

Tags: wcf-ria-services, datacontract

WCF allows you to specify a different name on the client than on the server:

```
[DataContract(Name = "MyClass")]
public class MyClassDC
{

}
```

How does one do this with RIA services?  Can I still use data contracts?

**Edits:**

I tried decorating my class with `DataContractAttribute` and setting the `Name` field.  It works well enough except that the name of the class on the client side is still the analog of `MyClassDC` instead of `MyClass`.  Does the `Name` field not work with RIA Services?

BTW, I am trying very hard to get out a version of my application using WCF.  I've had nothing but trouble working with RIA Services and I find it very limiting.  I know it saves time, but it has been nothing but headaches for me.  I love WCF.  But for the time being I need to release a version that uses RIA Services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible as of today.

You can change `Name` and/or `Description` of a property so if you set one as `Required` the client would see `Client Name is required` instead of `ClientName` (the real name of the property.

This will not (of course) change anything on the generated property you'll see from the client.

Comment: Yet another reason to switch back to WCF.  *sigh*

Comment: why is that a must to you? In my solution I have both RIA & plain WCF services. They both work well together and solve different problems...

Comment: Its not just this.  I've had some major annoyances with it.

Comment: I had some big bumps on the road too... it's pretty new and I don't think is being used broadly... the little examples work just fine, but when you need to go to a real scenario it gets harder... (like everything else :))

Comment: I really love WCF though.  I feel as though I have much more control over things, and it seems to work better with my development methodologies. And I love my POCOs; when I get to design a new POCO my heart skips a beat. :)  I'm weird.